# Ngrok + IIS Express and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication, iis-express, ngrok

Im trying to expose a web application I have developed in ASP.NET MVC 5 through ngrok and Im having no luck with the Windows Authentication.  My plan was to test the app using other VMs with IE8 (insert rage here) and a few mobile devices connecting through ngrok.

My setup details are as follows.

- VM with Server 2008 (Domain Controller), Visual Studio 2013, SQL etc and development tools
- Domain XYZ setup in VM with test users
- The Web App is running by F5'ing VS in IIS Express and uses Windows Authentication.  IIS express is configured to support Windows Authentication.
- I have configured ngrok bindings in the applicationhost config file and also run the netsh command "netsh http add urlacl url=URLPLUSPORT user=everyone"

I can access and use/debug the app fine on the VM using localhost, this has always worked.  However, when I run ngrok and then access the app from outside the VM I get the login credential prompt (was expecting this).  I enter the correct user/password and I still get 401 Unauthorised and cannot access the app.

Can anyone help? Do I need any extra configuration to allow the authentication to pass through?  Is this even possible?

I am pretty much stumped right now and the ngrok site is down although I cant imagine there is much documentation on this scenario :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue? I'm running into the same issue.